# Disable right sidebar in explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

How do I disable the right sidebar in the explorer which shows me how many items I have in the current folder or gives me further information about the selected item. Best would be to have a shortcut to show and hide the sidebar since I need it sometimes but when I work with many windows next to each other the sidebars are annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're talking about the details pane or the content pane, either way, there is a shortcut for both of them:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = Toggle content pane

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = Toggle details pane

Comment: I was talking about the details pane. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there also a shortcut for the navigation pane?

Comment: Not as such, but you can get around it by doing the following: 
1. Alt+V
2. N
3. ENTER (or) SPACE